# Unknown SMTP host: smtp.live.com

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-mail

Sorry for the Repeated Question.

But i'm not Understanding how this error coming ... when i'm Sending Mail (Using Hotmail)

Hear is My Sample Code..

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.live.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="narasimham@sitsonline.com" />
    <property name="password" value="**********" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But i got this Exception..

```
 org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.live.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.live.com. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.live.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.live.com; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.live.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.live.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1280)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:573)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ace25600.serviceMessage(<generated>)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ace25600.service(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.live.com
```

Comment: Not a JavaMail problem but simply the laziness of the question starter to figure out the correct SMTP domain name.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit strange.  The exception is saying that the DNS lookup for smtp.live.com failed.  Yet when I did a lookup for "smtp.live.com" I got this:

```
$ nslookup smtp.live.com
Server:     10.0.0.138
Address:    10.0.0.138#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp.live.com   canonical name = smtp.hot.glbdns.microsoft.com.
Name:   smtp.hot.glbdns.microsoft.com
Address: 65.55.162.200
```

So I suspect that either you've got a temporary / local DNS outage, or something is wrong with your DNS configs.  It is also possible that the DNS entry is in the process of being withdrawn ... and your upstream DNS caches expired it before mine did.

Try doing a DNS lookup yourself and tell us what it reports.  And if it fails, I suggest you look for a more up-to-date SMTP host for "live.com" / hotmail / whatever it calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

`smtp.live.com` is probably out-of-date.  The MX record for live.com points to mx1.hotmail.com through mx4.hotmail.com; try one of those.

Answer (score 0):

smtp.live.com should work.  Most likely you're behind a corporate firewall that prevents direct internet access so you can't look up the name.  The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).